# Setup GitHub Webhook for AWS EC2 server

Tags: github, webhooks

I have a web application deployed in an AWS EC2 instance. I recently learnt about GitHub Webhooks and I am now trying to setup a webhook service for my EC2 server.

I have two questions:

1. How can I receive the webhook payload to a specific endpoint on my server?
2. What will be the payload URL that I have to provide when setting up the GitHub webhook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to go to your repo, and click through this sequence:

> Settings -> Webhooks & Services -> Add webhook

Then paste the url where github will submit data for each new commit. You can find examples of payload in [example](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#example-delivery).

Then implement the logic needed in the backend to work with info about new commits.

Comment: i have just configure webhook, but it is giving me **Invalid HTTP Response: 404**, in **Recent Deliverers** Section. Means Request has been made from github but Response gives 404 error code.

Comment: You need to implement logic in backend to parse payload of github as I notice in answer.

Comment: ok. Is there any online resource to receive and parse webhook payload other than [github doc](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) from which i can write that logic ?